# When ToastProvider is shown I am not able to click other things on width line

Tags: reactjs, react-native, toast

I am using this package react-native-toast-notifications for my application. When toaster is display, I am blocked and I am not able to click anything in the length of the toaster.

How can I fix that?
That's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Colors } from '@utils';
import { Text } from '@components';
import { ToastProvider } from 'react-native-toast-notifications';
import { View } from 'react-native';

 interface IProps {
 children: JSX.Element;
 }

 export const CustomToastProvider = ({ children }: IProps) => {
 return (
<ToastProvider
  placement="top"
  duration={5000}
  animationType="slide-in"
  animationDuration={250}
  textStyle={{ fontSize: 20 }}
  offset={50}
  offsetTop={30}
  offsetBottom={40}
  swipeEnabled={true}
  renderType={{
    custom: toast => (
      <View
        style={{
          maxWidth: '95%',
          paddingHorizontal: 15,
          paddingVertical: 10,
          backgroundColor: Colors.BlackLight,
          marginVertical: 4,
          marginRight: 40,
          borderRadius: 8,
          borderLeftColor: toast.data?.type === 'error' ? Colors.Red : Colors.GreenSuccess,
          borderLeftWidth: 6,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            color: Colors.White,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'left',
          }}>
          {toast.data.title}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: Colors.White, marginTop: 2 }}>{toast.message}</Text>
      </View>
    ),
  }}>
  {children}
</ToastProvider>
);
```

};

Comment: I've tried with zIndex again same problem

Comment: Could you  share an image of what's happening?

Comment: please check your twitter